# How to load up pages in different directory without it affecting URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

My file structure usually goes something like this -

```
/images/  
/css/  
init.php  
header.php  
page1.php  
page2.php
```

etc ...

After basically creating more and more pages, its becoming much more difficult to manage them because it's essentially turned the root directory into a massive list of pages.

How can I make it so the pages are placed in a folder along with its associated category like this -

```
/pages/category1/page1.php  
/pages/category1/page2.php  
/pages/category2/page3.php
```

without it affecting the URL so it still looks like http://domain.com/page1.php

Will editing the .htaccess be the most effective method of doing this? or is there another way?

Comment: what happens if you end up with `cat1/pag1` and `cat2/pag1`?

Comment: The file names are unique just as they are now in the root directory. The only difference is they are more organized.

Comment: are each of these pages totally different from each other, or do they all share a common "skeleton" and simply some wording/pictures change? if they're all common, then don't have one-file-per-page. have one template page, and fill in the changeable data while building the page, then you have only ONE file, instead of hundreds/thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a singular php file in the root directory that basically got a PHP page from a $_GET request and then checked to see if the PHP page exists. If it did then I used `REQUIRE_ONCE` to get the page.

```
//Get page from $_GET request 
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
  $page = $_GET['page'];
}

//Create path including the page
$url = ROOT_DIR . "/pages/".$page;

//If the page exists include it, if not then show a 404 page.
if(file_exists($url)){
  REQUIRE_ONCE $url;
}else{
  REQUIRE_ONCE "/pages/404.php";
}
```

This allows me to access login.php in the /pages/ directory using

```
 http://domain.com/index.php?page=login.php
```

I then just rewrote the URL with .htaccess to make it more attractive.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1.php [QSA,L]
```

so that allows me to use

```
 http://domain.com/login
```